# Automatically add WebVTT subtitles in browser

Tags: php, html, nginx, mp4

Here is the situation:

I have a .mp4 file on my server.
When I make a request to it (https://domain.name/file.mp4) my browser automatically play it. I have a file.vtt subtitle in the same folder, accessible at https://domain.name/file.vtt).

Here is the html code I get when I request the file.mp4:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;"><video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
        <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
            <source src="https://domain.name/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I add this on my browser while inspecting the page:

```
<track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="https://domain.name/file.vtt" default>
```

the subtitle works as intented.

Is it possible to do it automatically? That if I request the file.mp4, the browser looks for a vtt file with the same name and automatically add it to player?

Should I write some php which will find those subtitles at each .mp4 file request? Is there another way to do it?

I didn't create any html code on the server side, nginx serves the .mp4 files when they are requested and I think the browser on its own render the player, am I wrong? Is it possible to do it only with Nginx?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. I have edited my post to make it more clear

Comment: You say "same name" which is *file* here, in that case you can use a variable , check if the file exists by sending a http request.

Comment: Yes I know the file exists, what I want is that the player adds it to the video.

Comment: well, in that case you can use a variable such as $filename = "file" and append it to source `src` and track `src`.

Comment: So I need to do it using php, right?
Should I write a rule in my web server conf to redirerect the .mp4 request to a php file that will do the thing?

Comment: (For now, I am rendering any html on the server side, I just serve file when they are requested, and the browser does the rest by rendering a player, that's why I would like having the option not to render html based on requests, if possible)

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is it possible to do it automatically? That if I request the file.mp4, the browser looks for a vtt file with the same name and automatically add it to player?"*

The browser does not search for any unspecified files. You must add the subtitle filename in the `video` tag of your html code.

Try :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;"><video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
        <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
            <source src="https://domain.name/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="https://domain.name/file.vtt" default>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The browser indeed does not search for any unspecified file. But can the webserver call php to generate html code specifying the .vtt files available depending on the .mp4 requested?

Comment: Yes, as long as the PHP echoes back such (generated) HTML code. If you try something just [**update your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45732487/edit) with the PHP code for possible advice.

Answer (score 0):

well this is interesting for me also :)

like this

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
        <source src="https://domain.name/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <here is a script that will generate available translations (track) in the current directory ? >
```

My available vtt always have file name like this:

```
file.vtt srclang="hr" label="Hrvatski" default
file.en.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English"
file.ger.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="ger" label="German"
file.fre.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="fre" label="French"
```

etc ...

Maybe javascript?